# 4-eyes-principal implementation on a contact & company system

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

### Requirement

We are building a rather complex system, where we need to manage contacts and companies (Entities).
Entities are managed by business users. They have multiple associations. For Example:

**Contact**

- ID=*42*, FirstName=John,LastName=Doe

**Company**

- ID=*111*, Name=Company 1
- ID=*222*, Name=Company 2
- ID=*333*, Name=Company 3

**Address**

- ID=456, City=New York,Street=Broadway,Type=Postal
- ID=789, City=Berlin,Street=Meier Strasse,Type=Residential

**Contact-Company-Association**

- ContactID=*42*, CompanyID=*111*
- ContactID=*42*, CompanyID=*222*

**Contact-Address-Association**

- ContactID=*42*, AddressID=*789*
- ContactID=*42*, AddressID=*456*

So Contact with ID=42 is associated to 2 companies. There more associations: So a contact can have multiple phone numbers, postal addresses, and so on ...

Entities have 3 States:

**1. InCreation** The Entity is created, some required fields are still missing; not ready to be used.

**2. Pending** The Entity is fully created, all required fields are filled in; not ready to be used

**3. Validated** The Entity is validated (by an user != the creator) and can be used

Once a entity has reached a validated state and one wants to modify such an validated entity, the modification has to be stored seperatly and is not allowed to modify the validated entity. So the once validated entity is still the one that is used by the rest of the system.
Then later, a business user != the modifier is able to validate those changes: By comparing everything that has changed. If he accepts those changes, the changes need to be applied to the original validated entity. Apply means that the values need to be copied to the original database record since the IDs are not allowed to change (they point to other entities systems)

### Question

How do i store those modifications?

#### Idea 1

A modification is just another record with a new state=**InModification**. But then i also need to double all associations and need to store a relation between original entity and associations since i later need to know what has changed (e.g. the postal address in new york is now in 5th street and now longer in Broadway)
This will create a lot of possible unneeded records, since the entity association tree can be large and alot of records have to be created just to fix a spellung in the name

#### Idea 2

Store modifications as a XML blob (we are using WCF to transfer entities from server to client, so those entities are by default serialisable). This what not touch the IDs and when the changes are applied later (extra care has to be taken for deleted and added associations). The problem that i see here are software updates. Once we change th entity structur in later updates, then there is the danger that old entity modifications that are kept betweeb 2 versions are no longer readable

Comment: I think you should look into event sourcing and cqrs, it seems well suited to managing the type of complexity you have here.

Answer (score 1):

idea 2 is better. Except the fact that you need to make some validation for the pending changes.So where ever an entity is being modified you need to first validate.If there exists some pending changes for this entity then it will now depend on the end user to resolve the conflict and he might choose to overwrite the old pending changes.In the end it will just over writing the pending changes, which is stored in the form of XML.
Or you might not over write the old one and can have two version of pending changes and then it will depend on the business user to finalize which one is better.So in this case you can have the pending changes in the form of XML like :

```
 <pendingChanges entityID="12333">
     <propertyName1>
      <version1 value="val1"/>
      <version2 value="val2"/>
    </propertyName1>
    <propertyName2>
     <version1 value="val1"/>
     <version2 value="val2"/>
     <version2 value="val3"/>
    </propertyName2>
  </pendingChanges>
```